# Trouble understanding Genetic Algorithm - Java

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I am currently working with a gaming code library and one of the parts uses a genetic algorithm for some of the AI. This concept is rather new to me and although I've looked up and read about how it works I am finding it hard how to link precisely what is being evolved, mutated etc. to the actual code.

The actions are basically each of the possible options that the AI has to move. So it is trying to evolve a state and find out which is the best action to take. Can anyone help me understand it a bit clearer than that?

```
private static double GAMMA = 0.90;
private static long BREAK_MS = 35;
private static int SIMULATION_DEPTH = 7;
private static int POPULATION_SIZE = 5;

private static double RECPROB = 0.1;
private double MUT = (1.0 / SIMULATION_DEPTH);
private final int N_ACTIONS;

private ElapsedCpuTimer timer;

private int genome[][][];
private final HashMap<Integer, Types.ACTIONS> action_mapping;
private final HashMap<Types.ACTIONS, Integer> r_action_mapping;
protected Random randomGenerator;

private int numSimulations;

/**
 * Public constructor with state observation and time due.
 *
 * @param stateObs     state observation of the current game.
 * @param elapsedTimer Timer for the controller creation.
 */
public Agent(StateObservation stateObs, ElapsedCpuTimer elapsedTimer) {

    randomGenerator = new Random();

    action_mapping = new HashMap<Integer, Types.ACTIONS>();
    r_action_mapping = new HashMap<Types.ACTIONS, Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    for (Types.ACTIONS action : stateObs.getAvailableActions()) {
        action_mapping.put(i, action);
        r_action_mapping.put(action, i);
        i++;
    }

    N_ACTIONS = stateObs.getAvailableActions().size();
    initGenome(stateObs);


}


double microbial_tournament(int[][] actionGenome, StateObservation stateObs, StateHeuristic heuristic) throws TimeoutException {
    int a, b, c, W, L;
    int i;


    a = (int) ((POPULATION_SIZE - 1) * randomGenerator.nextDouble());
    do {
        b = (int) ((POPULATION_SIZE - 1) * randomGenerator.nextDouble());
    } while (a == b);

    double score_a = simulate(stateObs, heuristic, actionGenome[a]);
    double score_b = simulate(stateObs, heuristic, actionGenome[b]);

    if (score_a > score_b) {
        W = a;
        L = b;
    } else {
        W = b;
        L = a;
    }

    int LEN = actionGenome[0].length;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        if (randomGenerator.nextDouble() < RECPROB) {
            actionGenome[L][i] = actionGenome[W][i];
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        if (randomGenerator.nextDouble() < MUT) actionGenome[L][i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(N_ACTIONS);
    }

    return Math.max(score_a, score_b);

}

private void initGenome(StateObservation stateObs) {

    genome = new int[N_ACTIONS][POPULATION_SIZE][SIMULATION_DEPTH];


    // Randomize initial genome
    for (int i = 0; i < genome.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < genome[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < genome[i][j].length; k++) {
                genome[i][j][k] = randomGenerator.nextInt(N_ACTIONS);
            }
        }
    }
}


private double simulate(StateObservation stateObs, StateHeuristic heuristic, int[] policy) throws TimeoutException {


    //System.out.println("depth" + depth);
    long remaining = timer.remainingTimeMillis();
    if (remaining < BREAK_MS) {
        //System.out.println(remaining);
        throw new TimeoutException("Timeout");
    }


    int depth = 0;
    stateObs = stateObs.copy();
    for (; depth < policy.length; depth++) {
        Types.ACTIONS action = action_mapping.get(policy[depth]);

        stateObs.advance(action);

        if (stateObs.isGameOver()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    numSimulations++;
    double score = Math.pow(GAMMA, depth) * heuristic.evaluateState(stateObs);
    return score;


}

private Types.ACTIONS microbial(StateObservation stateObs, int maxdepth, StateHeuristic heuristic, int iterations) {

    double[] maxScores = new double[stateObs.getAvailableActions().size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < maxScores.length; i++) {
        maxScores[i] = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    }


    outerloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for (Types.ACTIONS action : stateObs.getAvailableActions()) {


            StateObservation stCopy = stateObs.copy();
            stCopy.advance(action);

            double score = 0;
            try {
                score = microbial_tournament(genome[r_action_mapping.get(action)], stCopy, heuristic) + randomGenerator.nextDouble()*0.00001;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                break outerloop;
            }
            int int_act = this.r_action_mapping.get(action);

            if (score > maxScores[int_act]) {
                maxScores[int_act] = score;
            }


        }
    }

    Types.ACTIONS maxAction = this.action_mapping.get(Utils.argmax(maxScores));


    return maxAction;

}

/**
 * Picks an action. This function is called every game step to request an
 * action from the player.
 *
 * @param stateObs     Observation of the current state.
 * @param elapsedTimer Timer when the action returned is due.
 * @return An action for the current state
 */
public Types.ACTIONS act(StateObservation stateObs, ElapsedCpuTimer elapsedTimer) {

    this.timer = elapsedTimer;
    numSimulations = 0;

    Types.ACTIONS lastGoodAction = microbial(stateObs, SIMULATION_DEPTH, new WinScoreHeuristic(stateObs), 100);

    return lastGoodAction;
}


@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g)
{
    //g.drawString("Num Simulations: " + numSimulations, 10, 20);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`genome` is the encoding of the solution (genotype) which is translated by `simulate` into the actual problem space (phenotype). In addition a fitness score is returned as part of the evaluation. The other methods initialise or perturbate the genotype to obtain a different solution.

Please ask more specific questions, if you need more rather than dumping a whole lot of code asking 'please explain'!